# Want to git clone on a mounted sd card but it doesnt work

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mount

I want to clone a git directory on my WSL but I get the same error, I've tried a bunch of stuff that I've found online but nothing worked. I was told modifying the `/etc/wsl.conf` file would help but I cant modify files in /etc.

I don't know if it is because I mounted an sd card or not. The space I am using WSL on is an sd card added to my Surface Pro 7. Previously I just used WSL without it caused no problems but I was running out of space.

My generate sshkey doesnt work either. I've tried many things.

My main WSL directory still works
[image]

Do you think you can help ? Was I clear enough with my issue ?

[image: main problem]

I want to be able to use git on the mounted sd card.

I tried:

- modifying the `/etc/wsl.conf` file
- generating an ssh key from the mounted directory

Comment: This looks like your user does not have the proper permissions on the SD card. What are the permissions of the folder you want to clone in?

Comment: I allowed all the permissions in the folder in which I cloned.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As it is explained in [this askubuntu.com question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1115564) the reason is that you are accessing an NTFS partition from WSL. NTFS does not support the `chmod` call. However, if you were working on Ubuntu, this is hidden and the call succeeds even if it does not do anything. On WSL on the other hand the call results in an error, which is what you see.

The solutions outlined on the above mentioned page are:

- remount the partition with the proper options

```
sudo umount /mnt/c
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
```

(modify according to your partition and drive letter)

- create/edit the `/etc/wsl.conf` so that WSL automatically mounts using the correct options

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

(reboot to see the effects)

- clone to a different location that is not on an NTFS partition

Comment: I tried that before too. The partition is labeled as exFAT not NFTS. I cant create /etc/wsl.conf, it says that /etc is not writeable. The umount/remount doesnt change anything I get the same problem.

Comment: I would assume exFAT partitions to have the same issue, as they also do not have Linux permissions.